# spacyr not working for English module (but working for Spanish)

Tags: python, spacy

I just installed spaCy (Mac High Sierra, Python 2.7.14, spaCy Version: 2.0.6) using Anaconda (I was unable to do it through pip). To install it (in English and Spanish) I used the following code:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge spacy
$ python -m spacy download en
$ python -m spacy download es
```

I have checked that spaCy is working by running the following line in Terminal:

```
$ python -c "import spacy; spacy.load('en'); print('OK')"
OK
```

When I try to load it using spacyR in R, I get the following message:

```
> library("spacyr")
> 
> spacy_initialize()
Finding a python executable with spacy installed...
Error in spacy_initialize() : 
  spaCy or language model en is not installed in any of python executables.
```

Yet, when I load the Spanish module, I get no error:

```
> spacy_initialize(model = "es_core_news_sm")
Python space is already attached.  If you want to swtich to a different Python, please restart R.
successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.0.6, language model: es_core_news_sm)
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: Weird, indeed.  What happens if you specify the English model, instead of letting it default?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of `spacyr`, but if it also fails for `model = "en"`, one possible explanation could be that there's some problem with resolving the symlink shortcuts within the R wrapper. `spacy.load()` will check both installed Python packages (like `es_core_news_sm`), as well as symlinks created in `spacy/data`, to allow users to conveniently load models as `'en'` or `'es'`. ([See here](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#spacy.load) for details on how the model names are resolved during loading.)

Comment: @InesMontani If I specify the English model I get the same error message.

Comment: @Quixo1986 Does it work for `model = "en_core_web_sm"`?

Comment: @InesMontani using spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_sm") did the trick! Thanks for the solution.